# Can I unallocate space occupied by an element of a slice in Golang?

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to implement a queue using Slice. But the problem with slices is that, once sliced, the trimmed elements continue occupying space. Hence, I want to know if there is anyway I could delete the space occupied or in other words unallocate the space of the trimmed elements.

```
queue := make([]int, 0)
//Enqueue
queue = append(queue, 1)
queue = append(queue, 2)
queue = append(queue, 3)
//Dequeue
deletedElement := queue[0]
//--unallocate the space occupied by queue[0]
queue = queue[1:]
```

Comment: The space for dequeued elements will be freed after append allocates a new backing array.

Comment: @CeriseLimón no it won't. Append will re-use the capacity that's already allocated beyond the current length of the slice.

Comment: @Adrian Assuming that the queue is used, the capacity of the backing array will be breached and append will allocate a new backing array.  See the accepted answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @CeriseLimón at which point the application is allocating *more* memory, not less, and only *after* re-using the memory of the trimmed elements. I don't see how that could be considered "unallocate the space of the trimmed elements".

Comment: @Adrian The space for trimmed elements is never reused.  Slice operations do not access memory outside the range of the data pointer and the capacity. The reallocations will be approximately the same size in steady state.

Comment: @CeriseLimón outside the range of the capacity, yes, but that's not how trimming works. The trimmed elements aren't removed from the capacity, they're removed from the *length*. If you trim and then append, the memory allocated to the elements that were trimmed will be re-used for the elements being appended until the capacity is exceeded. There is no "relalocation" of "the same size".

Comment: @Adrian The question uses `queue = queue[1:]` to trim elements at the beginning of the slice.  The statement modifies the data pointer, length and capacity of the slice.  The question is about a queue, not a stack.  See https://play.golang.org/p/ndBNhg9xUzK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`queue` is a slice which points to a backing array. It doesn't matter how big portion the slice covers (or may cover when reslicing) of the backing array, as long as there is a reference to the backing array, it will be kept in memory. When there is no more reference to it, the garbage collector will free it.

When you add new elements to your `queue` using `append()`, if the backing array can't accomodate the additional elements, it automatically allocates a new array, copies existing elements over to it, and then the old array will not be referenced by the `queue` anymore. If there are no other references to it, it will be freed.

If you don't want to wait for this to happen, you're only option is to create a new array or slice, copy the queue elements to it, and update your `queue` slice header to point to this new slice (so the old one can be freed).

For example:

```
//Dequeue
deletedElement := queue[0]
//--unallocate the space occupied by queue[0]
queue = queue[1:]

newQueue := make([]int, len(queue))
copy(newQueue, queue)
queue = newQueue
```

You could simplify this a little:

```
queue = append(make([]int, 0, len(queue)), queue...)
```

As you can see, this is a costly operation just to free the space of one `int`. So you should not do this after each dequeue, but only if the unused space is really big.

Also note that when creating a new slice, you may use a bigger capacity so new elements can be queued without causing an immediate reallocation, e.g.:

```
queue = append(make([]int, 0, 2*len(queue)), queue...)
```

In general, I would never do this. If you use your queue, you will constantly queue and dequeue elements. So adding elements will naturally make this happen.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have one doubt. Lets assume in another scenario I actually have a reference to the trimmed elements. Meaning there's an underlying array to the slice(bigger than the slice). In that case, Garbage collector will not delete them right?

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh If you have reference to the elements got from the queue, that's OK. If you have reference to the underlying array (e.g. you store the `queue` slice in another variable), that will prevent the backing array getting garbage collected.